# Why $\nu_{t_1,t_2}(dx\otimes dy)=p(t_1,x_1)p(t_2-t_1, x_2-x_1)$ where $p(t,\cdot )\sim \mathcal N(0,t)$ is consistent?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\nu_{1,2}(dx\otimes  dy)=p(t_1,x_1)p(t_2-t_1, x_2-x_1)dxdy$ where $$p(t,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}.$$
I want to show that $\{\nu_{1,2},\nu_{2,1}\}$ is consistent, i.e. $$\nu_{1,2}(F_1\times F_2)=\nu_{2,1}(F_2\times F_1).$$

I'm not sure how to prove it
$$\nu_{1,2}(F_1\times F_2)=\int_{F_2}\int_{F_1}p(t_1,x_1)p(t_2-t_1,x_2-x_1)dx_1dx_2,$$
but why should it be equal to $$\int_{F_1}\int_{F_2}p(t_2,x_1)p(t_1-t_2,x_2-x_1)dx_1dx_2=\nu_{2,1}(F_2\times F_1).$$
This is not true ? is it ? (it appear in the construction of the Brownian motion using Kolmogorov extension theorem).

Comment: is this helpful? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3348869/consistency-of-a-family-of-probabilities-in-the-construction-of-a-pre-brownian-m/3352387#3352387